# New button after all elements have been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

4 rows are stored here. Each new row is displayed when the LOAD MORE button is pressed. Each row is displayed as it should and the code works without problems. When the end is reached, a Go button should appear pointing to another page.

What's the best way to do this? I have included the code as an example.

```js
function loadNextSeven() {
  let moveItems = $('#off-items-bucket .item').slice(0,7);
  moveItems.hide().appendTo('#on-items-bucket').fadeIn('medium');
 }

function isThisTheEnd() {
  let numberLeft = $('#off-items-bucket .item').length;
  
  if(numberLeft == 0) {
    $('#load-more').hide();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    loadNextSeven();
    isThisTheEnd();
 });


$('#load-more').click(function() {
  loadNextSeven();
  isThisTheEnd();
});
```

```css
.items-wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#off-items-bucket {
   display: none; /* REALLY THE ONLY LINE YOU NEED*/
  background-color: palegreen;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #000;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px 0;
  width:100%;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

button {
  width:200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items-wrapper">
    <div id="on-items-bucket"></div>
    <div id="off-items-bucket">
      <!-- put the items in the bucket -->
      <div class="item red"></div>
      <div class="item red"></div>
      <div class="item red"></div>
      <div class="item red"></div>
      <div class="item red"></div>
      <div class="item red"></div>
      <div class="item red"></div>
      <div class="item yellow"></div>
      <div class="item yellow"></div>
      <div class="item yellow"></div>
      <div class="item yellow"></div>
      <div class="item yellow"></div>
      <div class="item yellow"></div>
      <div class="item yellow"></div>
      <div class="item blue"></div>
      <div class="item blue"></div>
      <div class="item blue"></div>
      <div class="item blue"></div>
      <div class="item blue"></div>
      <div class="item blue"></div>
      <div class="item blue"></div>
      <div class="item green"></div>
      <div class="item green"></div>
      <div class="item green"></div>
      <div class="item green"></div>
      <div class="item green"></div>
      <div class="item green"></div>
      <div class="item green"></div>
  </div>
<button id="load-more">LOAD MORE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you stuck showing the "Next page" button after all "Load more" buttons have been pressed?

Comment: It would be helpful to add in some details of the steps you've tried so far. Saying that, my suggestion to solving this would be to add a hidden button and look in the isThisTheEnd method for a place in which you can show it.

Comment: as is the case with the answer, it's great. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to just rename the button when you get to the end. Then you can just test it in the `$('#load-more').click(function()` function.

First, move the `numberLeft` variable out of it's function so that other functions can access it. When `numberLeft === 0` just rename the button with `$('#load-more').text("GO ->")`

```
let numberLeft

function isThisTheEnd() {
  numberLeft = $('#off-items-bucket .item').length;

  if (numberLeft === 0) {
    $('#load-more').text("GO ->");
  }
}
```

In this function, just test for numberLeft and react accordingly.

```
$('#load-more').click(function() {
      if (numberLeft === 0) {
        alert("Go to next page")
      } else {
        loadNextSeven();
        isThisTheEnd();
      }
    });
```

```js
function loadNextSeven() {
  let moveItems = $('#off-items-bucket .item').slice(0, 7);
  moveItems.hide().appendTo('#on-items-bucket').fadeIn('medium');
}
let numberLeft

function isThisTheEnd() {
  numberLeft = $('#off-items-bucket .item').length;

  if (numberLeft == 0) {
    $('#load-more').text("GO ->");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadNextSeven();
  isThisTheEnd();
});


$('#load-more').click(function() {
  if (numberLeft === 0) {
    alert("Go to next page")
  } else {
    loadNextSeven();
    isThisTheEnd();
  }
});
```

```css
.items-wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#off-items-bucket {
  display: none;
  /* REALLY THE ONLY LINE YOU NEED*/
  background-color: palegreen;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #000;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items-wrapper">
  <div id="on-items-bucket"></div>
  <div id="off-items-bucket">
    <!-- put the items in the bucket -->
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="load-more">LOAD MORE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The load more button handler should have a condition to check if the action that should be performed is load more or go to the next page

Comment: It does. It's called numberLeft. If there are no images left, go to the next page

Comment: The title of the post is 'New button' - suggesting reusing the original button is not enough.

Comment: To me that's interpretable and semantics. This is a 'new' button in the sense that it looks and acts differently. If you're going to another page, why not just reuse and recycle?  At the end of the day, it's one solution and I don't know why it's downvoted. Feel free to post a solution that creates a new bit of HTML, there's more than one way to do this. As the first few lines of my answer say 'This is one way..'

Comment: Yes, the scarf area can also change. The main thing is that I can refer to another page. Thank you.